# Deploy a WPF user control in a Silverlight application

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight-4.0, wpf-controls

I have developed a user control in WPF which draws some graphs.

Now i have to show this user control in a Silverlight application (to show on ASP.net webpage).
Is this possible to use a WPF user control in a Silverlight application?

I have searched on Google, but have not found a satisfactory answer.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible to show a WPF control in Silverlight. They use two different runtimes so are not directly substitutable with each other.

You have a few options though:

- use [XBAP to show WPF within the browser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970060.aspx)
- rewrite your control so that you can [compile a version for Silverlight or WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee321573.aspx) (this is (was) quite a common way to do it)

**Edit:**
in response to your comment you seem to have some misunderstandings, I think you haven't understood the links I gave you. You may also have misunderstood what Silverlight is - just in case you have let me mention that Silverlight runs as a plugin within the web page, it isn't directly part of the HTML structure.

For the XBAP approach the WPF control/page is hosted inside a web page - just like a Silverlight control is. However you don't have direct access to the local filesystem or network filesystem (or databases running on the network) - *Silverlight is the same, to access a database you really need to go via a WCF service*.

With the second approach you have two versions (one for WPF, one for Silverlight) of your control and you use compile time targeting to dictate which control is built. You then use the appropriate control in the appropriate project.

Comment: First point is not possible because we have to shown graph on Web page And didnt understand your second point. can u please elaborate in detail

Comment: Slugster if i use your first approach XBAP to show WPF within the browser then in which control of WPF u suggest to draw graphs.I have drawn graphs in windows form Panel paint event.Searh on google I have found there is no paint event in WPF Further link suggest Canvas, http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/fr-FR/wpf/thread/280a1c7e-a043-4c9e-969a-7d92b907caea